# PDO SELECT [and - or]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table: product

```
---- id ---- send ---- get ----

---- 1 ----- jack ----- sedo ----

---- 2 ----- jack ----- imam ----

---- 3 ----- imam ----- sedo ----

---- 4 ----- imam----- jack----
```

I would like to select from product with PDO PREPARE

```
where (send = imam AND get = jack) OR (send = jack AND get = imam)
```

This seems not working at all.

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE (send = :send AND get = :get) OR (get = :get AND send = :send)");
$query->execute(array(
    ':send'         => "imam",
    ':get'          => "jack",
    ':send'         => "jack",
    ':get'          => "imam",
    )
);
```

How can i do this query ? thanks

Comment: You need to name each of your parameters something different.  Such as `:send` and `:send2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming your params

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE (send = :send1 AND get = :get1) OR (get = :get2 AND send = :send2)");
$query->execute(array(
    ':send1'         => "imam",
    ':get1'          => "jack",
    ':send2'         => "jack",
    ':get2'          => "imam",
    )
);
```